# Changing year to month and year in thesis.cls

Tags: document-classes

I am using this [thesis.cls](https://oit.colorado.edu/software-hardware/tex-latex/thesis-class/documentation-sample-files) for a thesis. The template provides year as shown here [image]

but I need month, year like this:[image]

```
\documentclass[defaultstyle,11pt]{thesis}
\usepackage{amssymb}        % to get all AMS symbols
\usepackage{graphicx}       % to insert figures
\usepackage{hyperref}       % PDF hyperreferences??
\usepackage[sorting=nyt, backend=biber, maxcitenames=2, useprefix,     doi=false, isbn=false, url=false]{biblatex-chicago}
\AtEveryBibitem{%
\clearfield{note}%
 }
\bibliography{MyLibrary2.bib}
\input macros2.2.tex
%%%%%%%%%%%%   All the preamble material:   %%%%%%%%%%%%

\title{Something long}

\author{M.F.}{M}

\otherdegrees{Bachelor of Arts in  \\ 
      UNIVERSITY \\
      FARGO, ND \\
     2017
      }


\degree{Master of Arts}     %  #1 {long descr.}
{M.A., Pelican Studies}     %  #2 {short descr.}

\dept{Department of}            %  #1 {designation}
{Bird Logic}        %  #2 {name}

\advisor{Prof.}             %  #1 {title}
     {Mmm}          %  #2 {name}

\reader{Dr.~Guy}        %  2nd person to sign thesis
\readerThree{Dr.~Gee}       %  3rd person to sign thesis

\abstract{  \OnePageChapter The answer to every question ever   % because it is very short

    }

 \dedication[Dedication]{ To all the pretty people. % NEVER use      \OnePageChapter here.

 }

\ToCisShort % use this only for 1-page Table of Contents

%\LoFisShort    % use this only for 1-page Table of Figures
\emptyLoF   % use this if there is no List of Figures

%\LoTisShort    % use this only for 1-page Table of Tables
\emptyLoT   % use this if there is no List of Tables



\begin{document}

\input macros.tex

\chapter{About birds}
\end{document}
```

I hope that this is enough info to answer the question. I'm not at a computer right now but the mwe should generate a document with the top info.

Comment: Can you please make a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228)?

Comment: Oh, dear, another `thesis.cls` question. (1) We cannot know which of the many, many `thesis.cls` files available you are using. (2) Almost certainly, the best advice is not to use the `thesis.cls` you are using. (Not certainly, but, statistically speaking, the odds are very good that the file is more trouble than it can possibly be worth.)

Comment: I provided a link to the one that I am using. I will not be using thesis.cls again that's for sure.

Comment: Why are you using Colorado's class at Oklahoma? In the US, by far the path of least resistance is to use a class customised for your institution already.

Comment: It was close enough that I thought I could make some minor adjustments. I have learned my lesson, next time I will begin earlier and attempt to write my own class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the documentation of the class: https://oit.colorado.edu/software-hardware/tex-latex/thesis-class/online-documentation.

You can change the year with `\degreeyear{}`.

```
\documentclass[defaultstyle,11pt]{thesis}

\usepackage{amssymb}        % to get all AMS symbols
\usepackage{graphicx}       % to insert figures
\usepackage{hyperref}       % PDF hyperreferences??

%%%%%%%%%%%%   All the preamble material:   %%%%%%%%%%%%

\title{This is the Name of my Thesis}

\author{I.~B.}{Scriptor}

\otherdegrees{B.A., North Dakota State University, 2005 \\
          M.S., University of Reno, 2007}

\degree{Doctor of Philosophy}       %  #1 {long descr.}
    {Ph.D., Rocket Science}     %  #2 {short descr.}

\dept{Department of}            %  #1 {designation}
    {Rocket Science}        %  #2 {name}

\advisor{Prof.}             %  #1 {title}
    {Ed Visor}          %  #2 {name}

\reader{Prof.~Rachel Goddard}       %  2nd person to sign thesis
\readerThree{Ms.~Thora Nea}     %  3rd person to sign thesis

\abstract{  \OnePageChapter % because it is very short

    Often the abstract will be long enough to require
    more than one page, in which case the macro
    ``$\backslash$OnePageChapter'' should {\it not}
    be used.

    But this one isn't, so it should.
    }

\dedication[Dedication]{    % NEVER use \OnePageChapter here.
    To all of the fluffy kitties.
    }

\acknowledgements{  \OnePageChapter % *MUST* BE ONLY ONE PAGE!
    Here's where you acknowledge folks who helped.
    But keep it short, i.e., no more than one page,
    as required by the Grad School Specifications.
    }

% \IRBprotocol{E927F29.001X}    % optional!

\ToCisShort % use this only for 1-page Table of Contents

\LoFisShort % use this only for 1-page Table of Figures
% \emptyLoF % use this if there is no List of Figures

\LoTisShort % use this only for 1-page Table of Tables
% \emptyLoT % use this if there is no List of Tables

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%       BEGIN DOCUMENT...         %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\degreeyear{December, 1234}

\begin{document}

\input macros.tex

\end{document}
```

[image]